# Python - Replacing repeated consonants with other values in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string

I want to write a function that, given a string, returns a new string in which occurences of a sequence of the same consonant with 2 or more elements are replaced with the same sequence **except** the first consonant - which should be replaced with the character `'m'`.

The explanation was probably very confusing, so here are some examples:

- `"hello world"` should return `"hemlo world"`
- `"Hannibal"` should return `"Hamnibal"`
- `"error"` should return `"emror"`
- `"although"` should return `"although"` (returns the same string because none of the characters are repeated in a sequence)
- `"bbb"` should return `"mbb"`

I looked into [using regex](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub) but wasn't able to achieve what I wanted. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In response to a comment that was deleted in the meantime - I'd like to add that I learned that `re` is a standard module. I have, however, failed to accomplish my mission even with regex :)

Comment: Ah, my comment, thanks for seeing it! I deleted it because I didn't finish reading the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is probably the best tool for the job here. The 'correct' expression is

```
test = """
hello world
Hannibal
error
although
bbb
"""

output = re.sub(r'(.)\1+', lambda g:f'm{g.group(0)[1:]}', test)
# '''
# hemlo world
# Hamnibal
# emror
# although
# mbb
# '''
```

The only real complicated part of this is the lambda that we give as an argument. `re.sub()` can accept one as its 'replacement criteria' - it gets passed a regex object (which we call `.group(0)` on to get the full match, i.e. all of the repeated letters) and should output a string, with which to replace whatever was matched. Here, we use it to output the character `'m'` followed by the second character onwards of the match, in an f-string.

The regex itself is pretty straightforward as well. Any character `(.)`, then the same character (`\1`) again one or more times (`+`). If you wanted just alphanumerics (i.e. not to replace duplicate whitespace characters), you could use `(\w)` instead of `(.)`

Comment: @SaucyGoat I tried... Oh well. I learned something new!

Comment: @theX thank you for trying - that's all I could ask of you!

Comment: There are a very few people on the internet who are actually encouraging and positive, making the internet better.